# Removing a tree and committing with Rugged

Tags: ruby, git, gitlab, libgit2, rugged

I'm trying to remove an array of directories in a git repo and make 1 commit for each directory removed. I'm using Rugged and Gitlab_git (which is more or less just a wrapper around Rugged) and so far I've managed to do everything I need to except the actually deletion and commit.

I don't see anything in the [Rugged Readme](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged) that explains how to remove an entire tree/directory. I tried using their commit example for a blob and replacing a single file with a direcotry, but It didnt work

I also tried editing the code they had for the tree builder, but it added a commit to my history that showed *every* file ever in the repo having been added, and then left staging showing the same thing. Nothing was deleted.

```
oid = repo.write("Removing folder", :blob)
builder = Rugged::Tree::Builder.new(repo)
builder << { :type => :blob, :name => "_delete", :oid => oid, :filemode => 0100644 }

options = {}
options[:tree] = builder.write

options[:author] = { :email => "testuser@github.com", :name => 'Test Author', :time => Time.now }
options[:committer] = { :email => "testuser@github.com", :name => 'Test Author', :time => Time.now }
options[:message] ||= "Making a commit via Rugged!"
options[:parents] = repo.empty? ? [] : [ repo.head.target ].compact
options[:update_ref] = 'HEAD'

Rugged::Commit.create(repo, options)
```

Any suggestions? Im still a bit fuzzy on the git internals, so maybe thats my issue.

Comment: did you tried http://www.rubydoc.info/github/libgit2/rugged/Rugged/Index#remove_dir-instance_method ?

Answer (score 2):

The git index doesn't track directories explicitly, only their contents. To remove a directory, stage the removal of all of its contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a [`Tree::Builder`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rugged/0.24.0/Rugged/Tree/Builder#new-class_method) that is based on an existing tree in the repository, which you can then manipulate as you want.

If you already have the `Commit` object you want to have as your parent commit, then you can do this:

```
parent_commit = ... # e.g. this might be repo.head.target

# Create a Tree::Builder containing the current commit tree.
tree_builder = Rugged::Tree::Builder.new(repo, parent_commit.tree)

# Next remove the directory you want from the Tree::Builder.
tree_builder.remove('path/to/directory/to/remove')

# Now create a commit using the contents of the modified tree
# builder. (You might want to include the :update_ref option here
# depending on what you are trying to do - something like
# :update_ref => 'HEAD'.)
commit_data = {:message => "Remove directory with Rugged",
  :parents => [commit],
  :tree => tree_builder.write
}

Rugged::Commit.create(repo, commit_data)
```

This will create the commit in the repo with the directory removed, but might not update any branch pointers if you didn’t use `:update_ref`.

It also won’t update your current working directory or index. If you want to update them you could [`reset`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rugged/0.24.0/Rugged/Repository#reset-instance_method) to the new `HEAD`, but be careful about losing any work. Alternatively you could just remove the directory with [`Dir.rmdir`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Dir.html#method-c-rmdir), mimicking what you would do when removing the directory directly.

Check out the [docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rugged/0.24.0) for more info, especially [`Tree::Builder`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rugged/0.24.0/Rugged/Tree/Builder) and [`Commit.create`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rugged/0.24.0/Rugged/Commit#create-class_method).